# How to change vscode extension source link

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

If I want to change the source link of the extension of vscode to update the extension, which file and which line should I change?Thanks.

Comment: but where is your code?

Comment: git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode    I can compile it. And I want to change the source link of the extension to update my own extension.